# Android AWS Appsync subscription does not fire events

Tags: android, kotlin, subscription, aws-appsync

AWS Appsync subscription does not fire events.I did not receive events from the socket. The watcher seems to work fine because if i pass a wrong token (for test) it fire onFailure event.

What i have done is:

Update my project gradle:

```
classpath 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-appsync-gradle-plugin:2.7.+'
```

Update my app gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.amazonaws.appsync'
```

and dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-appsync:2.7.+' 
implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.2.0'
implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1'
```

Put these files inside app/src/main/graphql

> queries.graphql

```
subscription subscribeToNotify($userId: ID!, $deviceId: ID!){ subscribeToNotify(userId: $userId, deviceId: $deviceId){ userId deviceId body } }
```

> schema.json (downloaded from console)

My configuration json is:

```
{
"UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/0.1.0",
"Version": "1.0",
"IdentityManager": {
    "Default": {}
},
"AppSync": {
    "Default": {
        "ApiUrl": "https://XXX",
        "Region": "eu-west-1",
        "AuthMode": "OPENID_CONNECT"
    },
    "Demo": {
        "ApiUrl": "https://XXX",
        "Region": "eu-west-2",
        "AuthMode": "OPENID_CONNECT"
    }
}
```

}

Manifest:
`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />



<service android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService" />
```

My activity:

```
 private lateinit var appSyncClient : AWSAppSyncClient
    private lateinit var watcher: AppSyncSubscriptionCall<SubscribeToNotifySubscription.Data>

    private var callback:AppSyncSubscriptionCall.Callback<SubscribeToNotifySubscription.Data> = object : AppSyncSubscriptionCall.Callback<SubscribeToNotifySubscription.Data> {

        override fun onResponse(response: Response<SubscribeToNotifySubscription.Data>) {
            runOnUiThread {
                Timber.i("Subcription onResponse invoked  $response")
                Timber.e("Subcription onResponse invoked  $response")
                Timber.d("Subcription onResponse invoked  $response")
            }
        }
        override fun onCompleted() {
            Timber.i("Subcription onCompleted invoked")
        }

        override fun onFailure(e: ApolloException) {
            Timber.e("Subcription ERROR $e")
        }
    }

override fun subscribeToNotification(userID: String, deviceID: String, clearToken:String) {
        try{

            Timber.d("subscribeToNotification INVOKED")

            val clientConfiguration : AWSConfiguration =  AWSConfiguration(this)

            appSyncClient =  AWSAppSyncClient.builder().context(applicationContext).awsConfiguration(clientConfiguration).oidcAuthProvider { clearToken }.build()
            //subscribeToNotify

            var app_event_subscription = SubscribeToNotifySubscription.builder().deviceId(deviceID).userId(userID!!).build()

            watcher = appSyncClient.subscribe(app_event_subscription)
            watcher.execute(callback)

        }catch (ex:Exception){
            Timber.e("EXCEPTION CONNETING "+ex.message)
        }
    }
```

When the backend send me a notification nothing appear in log console but i can read that the subsription is done:

> 2019-04-25 10:49:28.456 12082-12317/infinite_software.intelligence_center.intelligencecenter D/RealSubscriptionManager: Subscription Infrastructure: Adding subscription object com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.appsync.subscription.SubscriptionObject@4d109b1 to topic 156616541434/2b4hzivvqvdwzmcy4wibyy2sku/subscribeToNotify/85582f91c6e6a66749f4e0e9c4d74ea7abef52b2e4c0242517e5236d4d51be60. Total subscription objects: 1

and the scheduler that works (every X seconds):

> 2019-04-25 10:50:59.996
>   12082-12082/infinite_software.intelligence_center.intelligencecenter
>   D/AlarmPingSender: Sending Ping at:1556185859996 2019-04-25
>   10:51:00.006
>   12082-12082/infinite_software.intelligence_center.intelligencecenter
>   D/AlarmPingSender: Schedule next alarm at 1556185890006 2019-04-25
>   10:51:00.006
>   12082-12082/infinite_software.intelligence_center.intelligencecenter
>   D/AlarmPingSender: Alarm scheule using setExactAndAllowWhileIdle,
>   next: 30000 2019-04-25 10:51:00.033
>   12082-12350/infinite_software.intelligence_center.intelligencecenter
>   D/AlarmPingSender: Success. Release
>   lock(MqttService.client.dcuju2iftbdgplcvdamtlghzuu):1556185860033

I missing something ?

Comment: I would imagine that if you pass the wrong session token, it is expected not to work? Can you edit the question a little bit? Are you saying that it's not working because you pass the wrong session token?

Comment: I pass the right session token but no events are fired from the socket.

Comment: If you solved it, please consider [posting an answer](/help/self-answer). Adding `solved` to the title isn't going to help anyone else who finds themselves with the same problem

Comment: same issue ... no solutions yet..

Comment: please post your solution/observation ?